Transform a table with start and end dates columns into a time series
I have the results of a query in Grafana that looks like this:



start_date
end_date
job_name
status




2024-11-26 15:00:42
2024-11-26 15:10:42
JOB_A
1


2024-11-26 11:32:12
2024-11-26 15:13:42
JOB_B
-1


2024-11-26 12:00:02
2024-11-26 12:00:42
JOB_C
0



Is there a way to transform the table into a time-series per job_name, in such a way that all the data point between start_date and end_date have the value of status?
The goal is to visualize the status, per job, with the state timeline visualization. Similar to the following image with the corresponding timestamps and labels.


there probably is, seeing: Time series visualizations are the default way to show the variations of a set of data values over time, what did you try? Where did that fail, and why ?

I tried everything. All the transformations available in Grafana. But perhaps I'm missing something.

What are you expecting to see?  Something like this?: https://i.sstatic.net/rEHs5s8k.png   (I only just installed grafana....)

How do job_name and status relate to "Server_A" and "Up/Down/Warning" ?

Server X -> Job X; Up/Down/Warning -> 1/0/-1

Playing around with grafana will get you there...
I am new to grafana, and will stop when having this (not the wanted/needed graph, but I am out of time to play around with grafana):

For this Is created the data in my database (MySQL) using:
CREATE TABLE `grafana_test` (
  `start_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_name` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO grafana_test (start_date,end_date,job_name,status) VALUES
     ('2024-11-26 11:32:12','2024-11-26 15:13:42','JOB_B',-1),
     ('2024-11-26 12:00:02','2024-11-26 12:00:42','JOB_C',0),
     ('2024-11-26 15:00:42','2024-11-26 15:10:42','JOB_A',1);

Because you want a time_line, you want a value for every x minutes (I choose 5), so I created this view:
CREATE VIEW vw_grafana_test AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) as d1, end_date d2, job_name, status 
    FROM grafana_test
    GROUP BY end_date,job_name, status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(d1,INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), d2, job_name, status 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE d1 < d2 
)
SELECT * FROM cte;

see: DBFIDDLE
NOTES:

This is not a final answer
Grafana is a complex product, which requires time, and motivation, to get it right. (I am stopping because of the time.... )

